# powershell IF condition in a Variable

Tags: powershell, if-statement, switch-statement

I've been strugling on a little thing for few hours now, and I wanted to know if one of you have the solution (maybe i'm missing a little thing)

I got a switch for setting the condition in a IF but seems it doesn't interprete it as a if condiction

```
switch ( $CampaignStatus )
{
    "Complete"   { $CampainCondition = ($DateStr -eq (get-date  -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"))   }
    "Incomplete" { $CampainCondition =  ($DateStr -eq (get-date  -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"))   }
    "InProgress" { $CampainCondition =  ($DateStr -gt (get-date  -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"))   }
}
```

```
foreach($c in $CampaignList) {  
 $index = $index +1

    $DateStr = ConvertToFriendlyDate -Date $c.deadline
    if ($CampainCondition) { blablabla}
```

Any idea ?

I tried with quotes, without etc

Comment: `$DateStr -gt (get-date  -Format "MM/dd/yyyy")` won't work correctly. For comparing dates in string format, the year must come first.

Comment: It's a bit odd that you're comparing two of the same conditions as well. `Complete`, and `Incomplete` will return the same value. So, you really only need one. Another odd thing is your switch statement seems to be before your assignment of `$DateStr`, yet you are using that result to compare inside your switch. Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Yeah, but there is another switch which will pass in param another array, it's the same condition for different array and values

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [`Script Block`s](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks) to store those expressions and later evaluate them:

```bash
$CampainCondition = switch ( $CampaignStatus ) {
    "Complete"   { { $DateStr -eq (Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy") } }
    "Incomplete" { { $DateStr -eq (Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy") } }
    "InProgress" { { $DateStr -gt (Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy") } }
}
```

Then for evaluation, you can use the [call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#call-operator-):

```bash
foreach($c in $CampaignList) {
    $index   = $index++
    $DateStr = ConvertToFriendlyDate -Date $c.deadline
    if(& $CampainCondition) {
        <# blablabla #>
    }
    <# blablabla #>
}
```

---

As for the conditions themselves, instead of converting the date into a specific format `(Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy")` and then comparing that string with `$DateStr`, it would a much better idea to parse `$DateStr` as a [`DateTime` instance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) and compare that against today's date.

Comment: `-gt` is not gonna work as expected on mixed-endian date formats

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen well I agree, I added an update regarding that, thanks