# PowerShell if-statement with a condition in a string

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I have a condition stored in a string variable and I want to use this in an if-statement.

In this example there is always a match, as the variable is not zero or null, etc. It's not "executing" the variable as condition.

My wish is to "execute" the condition what is stored in the variable.

```
$myCheckTest = '$test -eq 4'
$test = 5

if ($myCheckTest) {
    write-host "TEST MATCH"
} else {
    write-host "TEST NO MATCH"
}
```

This works without the quotes like: `$myCheckTest = $test -eq 4` but the condition is externally stored in a json file.

I also tried `if ( & {$myCheckTest} ) {` as I think that this is comparable with JavaScript `if ( eval(condition) )` but this is still not giving me the proper answer "TEST NO MATCH" that I expect.

I am aware of [powershell IF condition in a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74391633/powershell-if-condition-in-a-variable) but here the condition is not in a string-variable like I have.

Comment: The variable $test is just a string inside single quotes and doesn't get substituted.  Use double quotes instead.

Comment: Thank you jdweng, but substitution is not what I want. The string in variable $myCheckTest comes from a json file, so substitution will not happen... I switched the first 2 lines in the example to make it more clear.

Comment: WHAT????  You if statement is always doing '$test -eq 4'  $test is always the string "$test".  So "$test" never will equal "4".

Comment: My wish is that '$test -eq 4' will be executed in the if-statement and that within the if-statement the $test will be replaced by 5, not before...

Answer (score 1):

You might use the [`$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions#executioncontext-expandstring) method to evaluate the string expression:

```
$test = 5
$myCheckTest = '$test -eq 4'
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString("`$($myCheckTest)")
False
$myCheckTest = '$test -eq 5'
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString("`$($myCheckTest)")
True
```

Note that the backtick (`` ` ``) prevents the first dollar to be substituted so that you actual string expression will be something like: `$($test -eq 4)`
Or in your function:

```
if ($ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString("`$($myCheckTest)")) {
    write-host "TEST MATCH"
} else {
    write-host "TEST NO MATCH"
}
```

A more common way to do thing like this is, is to use a scriptblock:

```
$myCheckTest = {$test -eq 4}
$test = 5

if (&$myCheckTest) {
    write-host "TEST MATCH"
} else {
    write-host "TEST NO MATCH"
}
```

Comment: Thank you iRon for such clear and complete response, I tested this in my actual script and this works as well. I shall read about both `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString` as about `Invoke-Expression` to see the differences.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression

A collegae pointed me to the `Invoke-Expression` command:

```
if (Invoke-Expression $myCheckTest) {
    write-host "TEST MATCH"
} else {
    write-host "TEST NO MATCH"
}
```

This works within my actual script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ScriptBlock.InvokeWithContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invokewithcontext?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) for this:

```bash
$myCheckTest = '$test -eq 4'

# Convert the string to ScriptBlock
$sb  = [scriptblock]::Create($myCheckTest)
# Argument to feed to the ScriptBlock
$arg = [psvariable]::new('test', 5)

if ($sb.InvokeWithContext(@{}, $arg)) {
    write-host "TEST MATCH"
}
else {
    write-host "TEST NO MATCH"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Santiago, nice to see extra options :-) but I have to say that this is a less readable then `if (Invoke-Expression $myCheckTest)`
Still it can be very useful in certain cases....

Comment: @Mauricevan'tLoo yup; agreed. The only problem with `iex` is no way of handling possible arbitrary code